# Extraction data confluence wiki

Tags: java, feature-extraction, confluence, data-extraction

I have a problem.

I'm trying to extraction data from confluence. I need like: Who is the user? When did he comment? What is blog? etc.
Which possible idea do you know that i can collect the data?

I know, if you have a DB you can collect with out from with DB.
Is JSON and XML also possible?
Other ideas?

I want creat than a Plugin Dashboard in Confluence.